# Generate Subscription with arguments in AWS AppSync with GraphQL Transform

Tags: aws-appsync, graphql-subscriptions

I’m currently using GraphQL transform lib to generate all my schema.
I have a model defined like this:

```
type Feedback @model {
  id: ID!
  event: Event! @connection(name: "EventFeedbacks")
  submittedDate: AWSDateTime!
}
```

and the auto-generated subscription schema is like this:

```
type Subscription {
    onCreateFeedback: Feedback
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createFeedback"])
}
```

I would like to have an argument for the subscription so that I can subscribe to that event only, like this:

```
type Subscription {
    onCreateFeedback(eventId: ID): Feedback
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createFeedback"])
}
```

What do I need to do to get this subscription auto generated? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Customizing the subscription fields arguments is currently not supported. The only supported customization is to create multiple subscription fields tied to a single mutation.

**Example:**

```
type Feedback @model(subscriptions: { onCreate: ["onCreateFeedback", "onCreateFeedbackById"] }) {
  id: ID!
  event: Event! @connection(name: "EventFeedbacks")
  submittedDate: AWSDateTime!
}
```

will generate for the subscription type:

```
type Subscription {
    onCreateFeedback: Feedback
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createFeedback"])
    onCreateFeedbackById: Feedback
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createFeedback"])
}
```

but then you will have to add the `eventId` argument manually on the `onCreateFeedbackById` field.

Though, I would suggest to open a feature request in https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues

Answer (score 2):

As @Tinou correctly outlines, you can rename and turn off subscription fields that are generated by `@model` using the `subscriptions` arg but you also the ability to create custom subscriptions by adding a `Subscription` type to your schema.

```
type Subscription {
    customField(arg: String): String @aws_subscribe(mutations:["customPublish"])
}
```

With this approach, you can add any fields and arguments that you need.

Comment: Before I was having error message like 'unknown directive @aws_subscribe'. Now I can compile after I switch to multienv branch of @aws-amplify/cli. Now the subscription with argument can be generated now, but no result is received after a mutation. Do I need to write a resolver for the subscription?